# Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Index property setter is not supported

Tags: css, google-chrome, react-dom

I am getting above error in my react project when chrome version is updated to 74 (latest version).

[image]

Comment: Have you found any resolution on this?

Comment: This seems to be the result of https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15375

Comment: Hi, How did you fix this?

Comment: This happens to me when I refactor my component from inline styles to classnames, but forget to update the attribute. e.g. `style={{ color: 'red'}}` to `style={styles.red_color}` instead of `className={styles.red_color}`

Answer (score 28):

The root cause of this issue is described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15375#issuecomment-490701560). Essentially this happens when you pass `style` property of some elemnt as `string` or `array`. Like `style="string"` or `style={[array]}`. This may seem not relevant (I don't think that someone intentionally try to send `string` or `Array` to `style` property), but in my case this was root cause.

To find error I recommend to carefully investigate your code with debugger in Chrome or other browser.

Below is example of my error

[image]

I erroniously set `styles.radioButton` (which is used as value for `style` property for some element) using spread operator `...spacing.xxSmall`, but `spacing.xxSmall` is just a string and spreaded to array with chars as array members. Previously properties with indexes (0, 1, 2, ...) of `style` has been ignored, but now site is crushed.

Answer (score 18):

I work with Angular libraries and some of them does not support inline styles now (for me it was ngx-avatar and it not working on Firefox and chrome: 74)

before:

`<ngx-avatar style="border-radius="50%"></ngx-avatar>`

after:

`<ngx-avatar [style.border-radius]="'50%'"></ngx-avatar>`

I think you can try the same for React.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue with ngx-avatar

Answer (score 3):

In my **RN Expo Web** application I was getting this error while doing something like

```
style={{ padding: 5, ...props.style }}
```

[image]

I Realized that passing prop named "style" and then using it as inline style was causing this error. What resolved it for me was using a different name for the prop and doing something like ...

```
style={{ padding: 5, ...props.listSectionStyle }}
```

Merely changing prop name from 'style' to anything else like 'listSectionStyle' (or any of your choice) should resolve if it is due to above stated reason.

Ref: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15375#issuecomment-490701560) shared by Fyodor in his reply helped understand the real issue.

Comment: In my case, also for an RN Web Expo project, the issue was using `styled()` on an imported component that was already styled. Doing the inheritance within the same file doesn't cause an error. I suspect that when they are in separate files it uses a string to set the style prop, which is the issue you link to.

Answer (score 3):

## For Expo/RN

You're probably giving an array of malformed stylesheets this way:

```
<compo style={[foo, biz, bar]} />
```

What you need to do is flatten your stylesheets:

```
import * as Native from 'react-native';

<compo style={Native.StyleSheet.flatten([foo, biz, bar])} />
```

Comment: I have the error with `@rneui/themed` 4.0.0-rc.8 in expo. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with prime ng's `<p-skeleton>`. What I was doing is passing a style directly to the skeleton like below:

```
<p-skeleton width="97.5%" height="20rem" style="margin-bottom: 2rem;"></p-skeleton>
```

So instead of using style directly I used the class property to give the margin bottom (my class was already defined). ***This removed the error for me.*** And updated line is as follows:

```
<p-skeleton width="97.5%" height="20rem" borderRadius="16px" class="mb-40"></p-skeleton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in *Next.js* . I used **style={style.cardImg }** instead of **className= {style.cardImg}**

So, replace style={} by className={}